# Doubt regarding definition of enthalpy

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

We define enthalpy change as heat released at constant pressure but it is also defined for process where pressure varies. How do I understand this?

Comment: Please provide examples. The way to understand it is that H is always defined for a thermodynamic system, and $\Delta H$ for a change between two systems. It doesn't matter if they have the same p and T. But if they do and only reversible pV work is done (no other type of work) then the heat released is  equal to the enthalpy change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the definition but equality, that is true just conditionally, for reversible isobaric changes with zero non-volume work.

If the process is not isobaric or reversible or non-volume work is done then, generally, $Q \ne \Delta H$ for given two states.

The equality is true if and only if $W = - p \Delta V$.

By other words, how could be the change of any state variable defined by a path dependent variable?

Comment: @ManRow Here we have another example...

Comment: @MetalStorm Mentioning users in comments works (unless changed recently) only to users who previously explicitly participated in Q, A or comments. (I tried it once but I was informed about it by a mod.)

Comment: Oh, thanks. I have contacted the user. Didn't know about that, I thought it worked...

Comment: @MetalStorm An example which also supports $\Delta H = Q$ for all isobaric processes (between equilibrium states) regardless of reversibility, since we can *always* say isobaric $W = -P_{ext}\Delta V$ where $P_{ext}$ is constant and well-defined, which happens to be the case in all isobaric situations regardless of reversibility (barring non-PV work and other such cases).

Comment: @Manrow Be aware that from TD and state variables POV, isobaric process need not have constant pressure, just the initial and final pressure must be the same. Therefore, Q and W can vary with different paths of irreversible processes, but the sum Q + W is constant. For irreversible compressions p_ext > p_int, the opposite for irreversible expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Enthalpy(H) is measure of heat contend in the system. It is a state function i.e. it depends on the initial and final state of the system.

We cannot measure the absolute value of enthalpy, we can only measure the change in enthalpy.

Comment: H is measure of energy of the system, modified by the pV term. It is not limited to thermal energy. Heat is not thermal energy, but its exchange. That is why we have $Q$, but not $\Delta Q$.